# Regressing I(1) variable on I(0) variable

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, stationarity, lags

I am dealing with time series regression, where I have stationary and nonstationary variables.
Can I regress nonstationary I(1) variable on stationary variable when controlling for the lag of the nonstationary I(1) variable?

I know regressing nonstationary variable on stationary variable would lead to bias. However, would it be okay if I control for the lag of the nonstationary variable in my regression.

My regression would be something like this in Stata (where y is I(1), x is I(0) and for illustration I use up to 3 lags of y)

```
reg  y_t+h    x    l(1/3).y_t
```

Answer (score 0):

No. If you truly have i(1) variables then coefficient at lag will be one. It is a unit root process, so regress the differences on x properly

Comment: Thanks. I thought about first differencing before. But I will estimate impulse responses afterwards. Will first differencing provide normal impulse responses, or should I estimate cumulative impulse responses? Also, I do not get coefficient as 1 when regressing on lags.

Comment: If the coeffiicient is not 1 then why do you think it is I(1) process? Run a unit root test on your y, then run with the lag and post what you get. The model you are estimating is called ARMAX(1,0,0).

Comment: You can do this with ARDL. See the bound testing approach that allows some variables to be I[1] and others I[0]

Comment: @Aksakal, recall that the distribution of the OLS estimator of AR(1) is peculiar when the process has a unit root. So no wonder the OP is not getting the estimated coefficient at 1 even if the true coefficient is 1.

Comment: @Richard Hardy? Can you even run OLS with a unit root (non-stationarity).

Comment: regression will run

Comment: @user54285, it is entirely technically possible. Whether / under what circumstances it may be a good idea is another question.

Comment: In the context of ARDL it is accepted. In fact that is why people use the ARDL version of cointegration to a large extent.  Because you can do this. Whether it is a good idea is far beyond my expertise.:)

Comment: I figured it out. Regressing on lags corrects for stationarity. This regresses time t+h on t. The method is known as Local Projections (Jorda,2005).